# Is there a way to force apex code return status code 400 on remote action without throwing an exception?

Tags: apex, javascript, javascript-remoting, remote-action

I have a remote action that throws a custom exception on apex side when an error occurs, and on javascript application, response occurs with status code 400. A new requirement forces me to save a record agter an error occurs but throwing exception rollbacks all DML operations. Is there a way to force apex side to return status code 400, other than throwing exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by making two different JavaScript calls to different remote methods.

Your first remote method would look something like this

```
@RemoteAction
public static Map<String, Object> firstRemoteMethod(){
    Map<String, Object> result = new Map<String, Object>();
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    try {
        // your logic ...
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Database.rollback(sp);
        result.put('success', false);
        result.put('message', ex.getMessage());
        result.put('details', ex.getStackTraceString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Call this from JavaScript using Remoting and on error call the second method to save error.

Second remote action

```
@RemoteAction
public static Boolean secondRemoteMethod(){
    Boolean result = false;
    try {
        // your logic to save error record ...
        result = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The idea behind using two separate calls is to split request among two different transactions. So, if your first actual transaction results in error, you can save a error record using the second async call.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am also thinking about making a secondary async call according to response from first async call but I am still curious about other possibilities, if they exist.